# Javascript - Select "not this" in a loop

Tags: javascript, loops, select

I have the following code to loop through some items:

```
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i+) {
    items[i].classList.remove('active');
}
```

Now I want to select everything, except the current item (and then run the rest of the code). Would it be possible to do this in a very simple way, like so: `items[!i]`?

Comment: What's exactly **current item**?

Comment: When does this loop work? `click` function? etc... Can u share more information?

Comment: Please share full code and proper explanation on what you want to select. This question is incomplete...

Answer (score 1):

> Would it be possible to do this in a very simple way,

Yes. Add an `if` in the loop:

```
for (var idx = …) {
  if (idx != currentIdx) {
    // change other items
  }
}
```

> like so: items[!i]

No.

*However* if you manipulate arrays and use a more functional style approach you can get close:

```
items.filter((el, idx) => idx != currentIdx)
     .forEach(item => item.classList.remove('active'));
```

Comment: I'm not sure that's what he meant, but I may have misunderstood, I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `splice()` on a duplicate array to select everything except `items[i]` in your loop :

```
var spliced;
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i+) {
    items[i].classList.remove('active');

    spliced = items;
    spliced.splice(i,1); // 'spliced' now contains an array without your items[i]
    // ... Do something with it ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use condition operator...`If(!anyValue)`

```
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i+) {
if(!currentItem){
    items[i].classList.remove('active');
}
}
```